# Laravelで作ったAPIのテスト方法　csrf対策で弾かれます

Tags: php, laravel, api

Laravelで作ったAPIをテストしようと
外部APIテストツールで値を入れて叩いて見たのですが、
POST/PUTメソッド　csrf対策されているのか
_tokenないと419error起きてしまいます。
どのようにテストしたら良いでしょうか。

Comment: [参考サイト](https://readouble.com/laravel/8.x/ja/csrf.html)

Comment: ありがとうございます！